# Signing certificate and uploading certificate

Tags: android, certificate, google-play-console

I have uploaded the first version of my app to the google play console, today I have tried to upload the second version but it gives me an error: the sha-1 signing certificate is different from the upload one and I can't upload the apk.
How can I generate a signing certificate that has the same sha-1 of the upload one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the same keystore (*.jks file) to sign your APK as you used when you uploaded the first version.

If you don't have the keystore anymore, then either you are enrolled in *App Signing by Play* and you can request your key to be [reset](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423?hl=en-GB), or if you are not, then you won't be able to update your app anymore: you'll need to create a new app with a new package name.